# Factor scores or mean values

Tags: factor-analysis

I obtained data from a questionnaire using a Likert scale. The data contains 20 factors corresponding to 4 constructs. In the end, I perform logit/probit regression. 
It is predetermined which of the factors correspond to which constructs. My question is, in which cases I perform factor analysis and in which cases I take the means of the factors to obtain the constructs. I would like to take the means - can you recommend literature where I find discussions about that and where I might find arguments in favor of mean values?

I further read that I need to consider whether the dependent variable is also a construct. Does it make a difference, when the dependent variable is a construct, when I choose between factor analysis and mean values?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `20 factors corresponding to 4 constructs` What is that? Did you want to say that there are 20 items (variables) and they are alotted among 4 constructs/scales/factors?

Comment: I use a questionnaire with 20 questions to obtain 20 single items. These 20 items are used to get 4 constructs. When doing this, the items are clearly matched with one of the constructs such that items 1-6 make up for construct 1, items 7-11 make up for construct 2, items 12-15 construct 3 and items 16-20 construct 4.

Comment: Did it get clear what I mean? -- Is it ok to compute the constructs from the means of the items, i.e. construct1=(item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6)/6?